# Знаки препинания перед "значит"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Обычно перед "значит" ставится тире, но если в первой части предложения, описывающей причину, стоит выражающее предположение "если", не уместнее ли будет поставить запятую? Например, в этом случае:
"Если ты так о нас думаешь, значит, считаешь нас злобными вздорными завистниками и не испытываешь никакой потребности в дружеских отношениях с нами?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Постановка запятой в таком предложении вполне соответствует правилам и примерам из литературы.

[**ЗНАЧИТ**, *вводное слово, союз и связка*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)

> 2. **Союз**. Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» **отделяется запятой (реже тире)** от последующей части предложения.
>
> *А **если** он в таком состоянии, что и чинить нельзя, **значит**, надо выбросить.* В. Войнович, Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина. ***Раз** эсер, то, **значит**, безгрешен!* Ю. Семенов, Непримиримость. ***Раз** вы читаете это мое письмецо, **значит**, я вас уже покинул и познал тайну смерти, которая сокрыта от вас за семью печатями.* Б. Акунин, Азазель.